# Why does this bash script terminate the calling process when it ends?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

When this bash script is run *backgrounded*, it terminates the calling shell. Why is this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# weird job control, background termination of parent shell problem
set -eum
echo "Do not go gentle into that good night"
sleep 1
```

Save this as `wat`, `chmod +x wat`, run it as `wat` - no problem. Run it *backgrounded*:

```
wat &
```

It closes my current shell!? And even more strangely, if that last sleep line is commented out, it can run backgrounded quite happily. Can anyone explain?

I understand that it's to do with the `-m` (job control) option to `set` but I don't understand why...

Comment: cannot reproduce. what bash version is yours?

Comment: 4.4 on MacOS `GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0)`

Comment: Can reproduce on Ubuntu `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605166/how-can-a-background-bash-script-exit-the-running-shell that maybe can help you, but I personally cannot reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Luciano, that sounds like exactly the same problem. I'll try and see what's odd about my bash config

Comment: Can also reproduce on a bare Ubuntu Xenial box `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` under Virtualbox, logging in via the Virtualbox UI, to be sure it's not something elsewhere in my own environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that happen if the script is run with Bash 4.3.30, but not with Bash 4.4.12. (The version of the shell running the script doesn't seem to matter that much.)

I didn't bisect that any further, but there's this in the [changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) that looks like it might apply:

```
This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.4-rc1, and
the previous version, bash-4.4-beta.

i.  Fixed a bug that caused background processes run from non-interactive shells
    with job control enabled to place the terminal in the wrong process group
    under certain circumstances.
```

Comment: I'm just writing some extra debug code to see if the PGID changes depending on the invocation; should be able to see it in action

Answer (score 1):

From man:

> -m      Monitor mode.
>
> Job control is enabled.  This option is on by default for interactive shells on systems that support it  (see  JOB  CONTROL  above).
>     Background processes run in a separate process group and a line containing their exit status is printed upon their completion.

from secure log:

> Received disconnect from X.X.X.X: 0

Seems, if we set to -m, the exit status is prints on a current shell after completion of a background process which is `exit 0`. Able to witness in securelog.

Comment: So are you saying that the exit status printed into the current shell, causes that shell to exit?

Comment: Secure log confirms the same